# Creating 'hole' in a RectF

Tags: android, android-canvas, rect

I have a canvas-based drawing app that when zoomed in, I draw a miniature of the overall drawing in one corner as a scaled `Bitmap`. I also have a small `RectF` that I draw over top of the miniature, which shows you where you are in the drawing. See first attached image.

[image: Miniature of larger drawing]

What I would like to do is to draw the scaled bitmap, then draw a `RectF` of the same size over top of it, with an alpha value that allows you to see the miniature, and then finally, punch a hole in the `RectF` that shows you where you are and allows you a clearer view of the miniature. See second attached image.

[image: RectF with 'hole']

I've considered using a bitmap for the `RectF` with the hole already 'built-in', but as the hole will both be moving depending on location, and will change in size depending on scale factor, I need to do it dynamically.

I've looked over the `RectF` docs but don't see anything that would allow me to clip the `RectF` with a smaller `RectF` that would make the 'hole'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Path` with filling option.
`moveTo` 0,0 and frame the whole minipic, then `moveTo` the first corner inside and frame/create the hole. Not sure if it works but you can also add shapes to the path.

Comment: Used your solution and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984308/how-fill-an-android-path-that-contain-holes-without-filling-the-holes) to solve this, thanks!